How to locate and click "reply" button on X using Python and Selenium
Trying to locate and click "reply" button using Python and Selenium.
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@data-testid="reply"]')))
reply_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@data-testid="reply"]')
reply_button.click()

got error:
File "C:\Users\Snake D. Plissken\Desktop\Project Blackwall\pythonProject\main.py", line 25, in follow_user
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@data-testid="reply"]')))
  File "C:\Users\Snake D. Plissken\Desktop\Project Blackwall\pythonProject\.venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 105, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 
Stacktrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7929FEEB2+31554]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF792977EE9]

How to click this button using Selenium? What is wrong with my code?

Can you share the HTML of the page in the form of text? Pl. read How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

What's the timeout value configured to? Is the identifier correct? - The timeout exception occurs if it's not found within the given time. A bad identifier returns the same exception as a very slow page. Put in a breakpoint and debug the code. Then you'll identify sync issues vs identifiication issues

code is simple:
driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, 300);")
try:
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@data testid="reply"]')))
reply_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@data-testid="reply"]')
reply_button.click()
except:
print("Cant find button")
time.sleep(500)
Always get error from exept "Cant find button"
